# Web application running without a name

Tags: java, web-services, web, intellij-idea, jersey

I just made a simple web application (using java and jersey as i want to start making a rest endpoint). I am working on intelliJ idea

I used [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=skltzZH7i4w) to build it.

I gave the project a name, group id and artifact.

Now when i run it in my local tomcat server, it runs successfully but does not show me the name of my web application in URL. It only shows localhost:8080 as can be seen in the screen shot below.

[image]

Why is it displayed like that? How can i give my application a name/URL?

Comment: The URL depends on how the app is deployed to the servlet container. However, host and port will always be that of the machine running the app. The text in the tab is set with the `<title>` element in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what i was looking for was to set the application context in tomcat server.

Here is how i did it: On IntelliJ idea, clicked on 'Edit configuration' -> than on 'Deployment' tab.
There is an option for "application context' there. I give it the name of my application(or any name that i like) and click 'apply' and restarted the server.

Here is how it appears in the browser now:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to watch this video first: [Domains and the Domain Name System](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ip0JSUgU4os) and then fully understand what the following paragraph means. Then your question will solve itself. Good luck! :D

`localhost` is the `IP` address of the `server` where the `tomcat` (which is an `application server`) is running. `8080` is the `port`. The `localhost` maps (from Windows hosts file) to `127.0.0.1` and this is a `loopback` IP address (meaning that it is, in fact, yourself).

p.s. that's what about the name in the URL. About the actual browser tab name, it's the `<title>` HTML tag.

> How can i give my application a name/URL?

You need to buy a domain name.